# External Native Build Issues after updating Android studio 3.0

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, ndk-build

After updating Android Studio 3.0, getting some External Native Build Issues.

\build\core\setup-toolchain.mk
No such file or directory

\build\core\build-all.mk
Android NDK: WARNING: No modules to build  your APP_MODULES definition is probably incorrect!

Below is the screen shot for more info.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnsBx.png)

Comment: What if you rename your directory to something that doesn't contain a `#`?

Comment: yes @Michael . I get it thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i observed from @Michael's comment. 
In my case am not passing proper path to the root of my project to ndk-build.cmd

So the root of my project path include hash(#) symbol. It was the problem to making my build.

I just corrected it. Now its working, when avoiding some symbols. Thanks again @Michael.